# Loop through custom template hooking thing

Tags: php, arrays, templates

I am building a template system for emailing people that currently works in the format of:

```
$array['key1'] = "text";
$array['key2'] = "more text";

<!--key1--> // replaced with *text*
<!--key2--> // replaced with *more text*
```

For this particular project I have a nested array with this kind of structure:

```
$array['object1']['nest1']['key1'] = "text";
$array['object2']['next1']['key1'] = "more text";

<!--[object1][nest1][key1]--> // replaced with *text*
<!--[object2][nest1][key1]--> // replaced with *more text*
```

The `<!-- .. -->` would be placed inside a HTML file which is then loaded into a string. The top example shows that I am replacing the comments with the data.

What would be the best way to do this in PHP? I thought I could loop through the arrays but then I just lost my trail of thought and got lost in what I was doing!

All help would be appreciated!!
Thanks

Comment: So, you want to replace array-like parts from a string with the content in the array?

Comment: Kind of yeah... its more of a template engine

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2171963/php-array-as-variable-name

Comment: no because thats for more php, this is for iterating over a file (or string) to replace the text.

Comment: no matter what, you need to extract the text-to-replace from the template file. Once you do that, it's the same problem. See if any answers you get differ significantly from the answers for that question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, using eval is dangerous, but if all the code ran though it is by you, it won't hurt. You can try this:

```
<?php

$array['object1']['nest1']['key1'] = "text";
$array['object2']['nest1']['key1'] = "more text";

$str = "sadfadsfjäadsföljadsölf
<!-- ['object2']['nest1']['key1'] -->
asdföadsjlf";

$split = explode('
',$str); // This sucks, you can use \n to detect line-breaks. Doesn't work that way in this example

foreach($split as $key => $value) {
    if(preg_match('/\<\!\-\- (\[.+\]) \-\-\>/e',$value,$matches)) {
    eval("echo \$array".$matches[1].";");
    echo "\n";
} else {
    echo $value."\n";
}
}

?>
```

Pretty weird way, but I couldn't figure out any clearer.

Comment: "If eval() is the answer, you're almost certainly asking the wrong question."

Comment: That's what I mean with my first line, but this is the clearest way to do this I think.